# Svelte component doesn't re-render when its props change

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm new to Svelte and coming from React, I am not sure I understand Svelte reactivity correctly.

Let's say I have a Parent component that fetches data asynchronously and passes the data to its Child component.

```html
<!-- Parent -->
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte'
    
    let options = []
    $: console.log('Parent-options', options)
    
    onMount(async () => {
        options = await Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3])
    })
</script>

<div>
    <Nested {options} />
</div>
```

```html
<!-- Child -->
<script>
    const { options, ...restProps } = $$props
    $: console.log('Child-options', options)
</script>

<div>
    The value is {options}
</div>
```

As you can see the console.log, both the Parent and the Child components log an empty array.
Then the Parent component logs the fetched data.
But the Child component never re-renders with the updated data.

EDIT:
Exposing props is done with the `export` keyword.

```html
export let options
```

and svelte documentation states

> $$props references all props that are passed to a component, including ones that are not declared with export. It is not generally recommended, as it is difficult for Svelte to optimise. But it can be useful in rare cases – for example, when you don't know at compile time what props might be passed to a component.

But in fact I'm wrapping a `<select>` component so I don't know the number of props that will be passed before compile time. Hence I use `$$props` instead of listing them all.

In typescript this is my types

```js
import type { HTMLSelectAttributes } from 'svelte/elements'

type Option = {
  id: string
  value: string
  label: string
}

type $$Props = HTMLSelectAttributes & {
  options: Option[]
}
```

What is the correct way to receive an arbitrary number of props in the Child components?

Available REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/849468dd89f143fdbf8a12dd16568647?version=3.55.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `const`, the value will never change after the first assignment:

```js
const { options, ...restProps } = $$props
```

That destructuring has to be reactive as well:

```js
$: ({ options, ...restProps } = $$props);
```

If you know that you need `options`, you can just export that explicitly. Svelte already provides a special value `$$restProps` that contains everything that is not exported.

Comment: You mean if I want to extend the select component with additional props I just explicitly export those props and I spread $$restProps inside `<select {...$$restProps}>`. Should $$restProps be reactive as well? `$: (rest = $$restProps); <select {...rest}>`

Comment: Everything in the template is reactive by default, there is no need to reassign `$$restProps` to an intermediary variable.